# Operator < cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'? What needs to be fixed?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form   
{ 
    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (yearworktextBox2.Text < 2 "Rejected")
```

I am trying to do if statements but I keep getting an error. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you intend `2 "Rejected"` to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Textbox.Text` is a string type and you are comparing it to an integer.  You need to parse your textbox value first.

```
if (int.Parse(yearworktextBox2.Text) < 2 || yearworktextBox2.Text == "Rejected")
```

However, if your textbox value is not parsable to an integer, it will throw an exception, which seems very likely, since you seem to be expecting either "Rejected" or a numeric value.  You can parse it outside of your if statement with a `TryParse`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int textboxValue;
    int.TryParse(yearworktextBox2.Text, out textboxValue);

    if (textboxValue < 2 || yearworktextBox2.Text == "Rejected")
```